# Gstreamer basic pipeline running but not displaying on windows 7 virtualbox

Tags: c++, windows, gstreamer

I am currently working with Gstreamer on Windows 7 (x86_64) as a VM (Virtualbox) and I wanted to run a basic pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=snow ! autovideosync
```

When I run this pipeline I get:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED...
Pipeline is PREROLLING
```

And then an error occurs:

```
Pipeline doesn't want to preroll
```

I solved this error by adding async-handling=true at the end of the pipeline but nothing is still displaying...

I tried to run the same pipeline writing C++ code. Here is a simple main you can run. When I run this code, I get no error but nothing is displaying.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
GMainLoop *loop;
GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink;

g_print("Starting...");
/* Initialisation */
gst_init(&argc, &argv);

g_print("Loop is created...");
loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

/* Create gstreamer elements */
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("gst-app-sink");
source = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "src");
sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink");

if (!pipeline || !source || !sink) {
    g_printerr("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
}

/* Set up the pipeline */

/* we add all elements into the pipeline */
/* source | sink */
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, sink, NULL);

/* we link the elements together */
/* src -> sink */
gst_element_link(source, sink);

/* Set the pipeline to "playing" state*/
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

/* Iterate */
g_print("Running...\n");
g_main_loop_run(loop);

/* Out of the main loop, clean up nicely */
g_print("Returned, stopping playback\n");
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

g_print("Deleting pipeline\n");
gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
g_main_loop_unref(loop);

return 0;
```

}

I really don't know where it could come from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the VM doesn't enable 2D and 3D video acceleration which is necessary to display these kind of stream. Just right-click on you VM -> Settings -> Display and check "Enable 3D acceleration" and "Enable 2D Video Acceleration".